# ArrayList Error, App Crashes

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, mpandroidchart

I have the following problem. I have a two `fragment` application with a static `arraylist` which is used in both `fragments`.

The occurance of the error can be described like this:

1. Add `entries` to `arraylist` (***FragmentA***)
2. Hit button, display `arraylist` in chart (***Fragment B***)
3. Go back to ***Fragment A***, add another `entrie` to `arraylist` -> error occurs, app crashes

The code of the fragments is this:

- **Fragment A**

  ```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick (View view) {



              if (editText3.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Item ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;
              }

              else if (editText2.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a Valid Quantitiy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;

              }

              else {

                  String nomen = (editText3.getText().toString());
                  float number = Float.parseFloat(editText2.getText().toString());

                  entries.add(new PieEntry(number, nomen));

                  editText3.setText("");
                  editText2.setText("");
                  editText3.requestFocus();
              }
          }
      });
  ```
- **Fragment B**

  ```
   button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick (View view) {
      getResources().getColor(R.color.violp);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.bluep);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.redp);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.greenp);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.yellowp);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.orangep);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.lightbluep);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.purplep);
      getResources().getColor(R.color.darkredp);

      PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(entries, "");


      set.setColors(new int[]{R.color.bluep, R.color.greenp, R.color.violp, R.color.redp, R.color.yellowp, R.color.orangep, R.color.lightbluep, R.color.purplep, R.color.darkredp}, getActivity());
      PieData datax = new PieData(set);
      piechart.setData(datax);

      Toast.makeText(getActivity(), (R.string.loading),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      piechart.setNoDataText(String.valueOf(R.string.nodata));
      piechart.notifyDataSetChanged();
      piechart.animateX(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);
      piechart.animateY(2000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInExpo);



      }



  });
  ```

**THE ERROR IM GETTING IS THIS:**

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

If some expereienced experts could help me out I would be very grateful.
Thanks.

*UPDATE: ERROR STACK INCLUDED*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nextpietwo, PID: 2528
                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.PieChartRenderer.drawDataSet(PieChartRenderer.java:244)
                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.PieChartRenderer.drawData(PieChartRenderer.java:147)
                      at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart.onDraw(PieChart.java:126)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17185)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please include the Error Stack as it is hard to figure out which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: done :) hope it helps

Comment: What is `entries`? Where & how has it been defined?

Comment: Could be a bug in the library. Maybe post this on github.

Comment: Entries is a new entrie in the PieData arraylist. Sorry, i forgot to include it bceause it is initiaized in the MainActivity.java so i can use it in both Fragment A and B.

Comment: Will do, but i've seen that the error in general is a rather common issue so I posted here as well. @shmosel

Comment: How are you initializing `entries` in your MainActivity?

Comment: `static List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPAndroidChart cannot shield you from the effects of not [separating model and view layers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and from issues with the managing the [lifecycles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) of Fragments and Activities. Please note that "communicating" between Fragments (such as one Fragment manipulating the data of another) is [not recommended by Google](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> Two Fragments should never communicate directly

Although `Entry` may look like a member of the model layer, it is actually designed to be tightly coupled with `PieChart` which is part of the view layer. It definitely should *not* outlive the View with which it is associated and if you want to avoid errors such as the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, the backing List lifecycle should coincide with that of the Fragment in which it is used. This does not mean that you can never add/remove from a `List<Entry>` once this is part of a `PieChart` - MPAndroidChart will allow you to do this within the above constraints.

To fix the above error, I would suggest a different approach than sharing a static object which is almost never a good idea in Android. You could share, instead, a separate model layer which contains the data you will use to construct the `List<Entry>`. When Fragment A updates the model, you can use an event to trigger rebuilding of the chart from the data inside Fragment B.

You have stated in the comments that you are using a `ViewPager`. The `ViewPager` uses `fragmentTransaction.show()` and `.hide()` and generally keeps the Fragments in a resumed state. Perhaps the easiest solution is to override `onHiddenChanged` as this is always called when the `ViewPager` switches to a new page. I think (not 100% sure) that you will also need a call in `onActivityCreated(View v)`.

So, you would have something like this:

```
@Override
onActivityCreated(View v) {
    //get updated model from Activity
    //rebuild chart from updated model
}

@Override 
onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    if (hidden == false) {
        //get updated model from Activity
        //rebuild chart from updated model
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick detailed reply. I will make this the answer to my problem. I am using a viewpager application by the way.. how would this affect the possible solution to my problem?

Comment: I'm glad it helps - I'll update my answer now to reflect a possible solution for `ViewPager`